# Query with JOINs (including self join on large table) taking an extremely long time

Tags: xml, postgresql

Trying to do a self-join on `event_att` to find events with attributes that fall under both criteria. Then, joining the results with `event` and `survey` to get info about those events.

`event_att` has ~6 million rows, `event` has ~100k and `survey` has only a thousand.

The below command has been running for two hours so far.

Am I doing anything obviously stupid? Is there otherwise a way to optimize this query?

```
SELECT survey_name,survey_code,resource_id,event_code as sample_event_id 
FROM (SELECT event_id FROM event_att WHERE att_type ILIKE '%device%' AND att_value ILIKE '%unconsolidated%') AS table_a
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT event_id FROM event_att WHERE att_type ILIKE '%biotope%') AS table_b
ON table_a.event_id = table_b.event_id
INNER JOIN event
ON event.event_id = table_a.event_id
INNER JOIN survey
ON survey.survey_id = event.survey_id;
```

EXPLAIN:

```
                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=190607.44..205883.35 rows=1 width=113)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=190607.16..205883.04 rows=1 width=38)
         Join Filter: (event_att_1.event_id = event_att.event_id)
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=190606.73..197718.59 rows=1040 width=70)
               Hash Cond: (event.event_id = event_att_1.event_id)
               ->  Seq Scan on event  (cost=0.00..6519.34 rows=155234 width=54)
               ->  Hash  (cost=190593.73..190593.73 rows=1040 width=16)
                     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=190572.93..190583.33 rows=1040 width=16)
                           Group Key: event_att_1.event_id
                           ->  Seq Scan on event_att event_att_1  (cost=0.00..190130.05 rows=177151 width=16)
                                 Filter: (att_type ~~* '%biotope%'::text)
         ->  Index Scan using event_att_event on event_att  (cost=0.43..7.84 rows=1 width=16)
               Index Cond: (event_id = event.event_id)
               Filter: ((att_type ~~* '%device%'::text) AND (att_value ~~* '%unconsolidated%'::text))
   ->  Index Scan using survey_pkey on survey  (cost=0.28..0.30 rows=1 width=107)
         Index Cond: (survey_id = event.survey_id)
```

Comment: What does EXPLAIN say?

Comment: One suspicious thing are the ILIKE matches starting with '%'; that's unlikely to use any but the most specialised index. Any way you could do that differently, or at least cut down the number of rows before doing the ILIKE?

Comment: @sabik added EXPLAIN output. The '%' pattern matching is unfortunately necessary given the non-standardized nature of the attribute types and values.

Comment: Thanks for the EXPLAIN; looks like it's indeed going through the whole `event_att` table ("Seq Scan on event_att") to do one of the ILIKE matches.

Comment: @sabik, yeah I figured it would have to go through that table twice, and I know pattern matching is relatively slow, but for five million rows there's no reason it should be taking two hours to do that.

Comment: It may also be mis-estimating; 190000 doesn't feel like it should be multiple hours. I guess it doesn't have much to go on as far as frequency of ILIKE matches is concerned. That's likely incidental, though; the main problem will be the scan through the big table. Can you eliminate it?

Comment: If you can't change the schema or pre-filter on something, and you need to do these queries often, the index type to consider would be "trigram".

Comment: Another option would be to add a new table, mapping the flags (like "device") to the rows of the table. Then you could use a plain index on that

Comment: Trigram index docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.40.8

Comment: BTW, what are the load metrics on the DB server? Is it maxing out CPU, I/O, network? Any swap use? Has the configuration been tuned for performance?

Comment: It's also doing a scan on the `event` table; that could be either because it's expecting to match a lot of it, or there's no index on the `event.event_id` column

Comment: I'll turn these into an answer...

Comment: PS: Another option, especially in the cloud: upgrade the server :-)

Comment: If those estimates are even remotely accurate, this should not take 2 hours, even if it is quite inefficient.  So you should start by doing VACUUM ANALYZE on all tables.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: What is the setting of work_mem?

Answer (score 0):

The first suspicious thing are the ILIKE matches starting with '%'; that's unlikely to use any but the most specialised index. The EXPLAIN confirms that, it's indeed going through the whole `event_att` table ("Seq Scan on event_att") to do one of the ILIKE matches.

- Any way you could do that differently, or at least cut down the number of rows before doing the ILIKE?
- If you can't change the schema or pre-filter on something, and you need to do these queries often, the index type to consider would be "[trigram](http://postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.40.8)"; that should be able to speed up ILIKE searches.
- Another option would be to add a new table, mapping the flags (like "device", "unconsolidated", etc) to the rows of the `event_att` table. Then you could use a plain index on that. That would be a schema change, though; you'd need to keep the new table updated...

Other potential issues or items to check:

- The EXPLAIN may be mis-estimating; 190000 doesn't feel like it should be multiple hours. I guess it doesn't have much to go on as far as frequency of ILIKE matches is concerned.
- What are the load metrics on the DB server? Is it maxing out CPU, I/O, network? Any swap use? Has the configuration been tuned for performance?
- Can you increase the server specifications easily, especially the RAM? Sometimes brute force can do the trick, especially in the cloud where upgrading is only a reboot away.
- It's also doing a scan on the `event` table; that could be either because it's expecting to match a lot of it (especially if the records are small), or there's no index on the `event.event_id` column.